# any way to approach a sequency with a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Suppose there is a finite sequence $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_k)$, is there any way to use a polynomial $\alpha_2 x^2 + \alpha_1 x + \alpha_0$ to generate that sequence such that each coefficient could be given with one set of $\alpha$, i.e. $a_j=\alpha_2 j^2 + \alpha_1 j + \alpha_0$?

Comment: The notation $\Sigma_m$ is rather vague. Please be as precise as possible.

Comment: I updated the question and let's consider the simple case with only degree-2 polynomial first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To prescribe $k+1$ values of a polynomial, you need in general a polynomial of degree $k$, though you might get lucky and have the values turn out to fit a lower-degree polynomial perfectly.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial